# Ubuntu 12.04 on beaglebone ¿hard float or soft float?

Tags: ros, beaglebone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm planning on getting the ROS installed to a beaglebone. I'm looking for information about hard vs soft float. They are incompatible at the ABI level, and you are not supposed to mix them. I understand that I'm gonna have to build everything from source, so is it ok to go the hard float way? Or is there a chance I get a call to a soft float library and everything breaks?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34515/ubuntu-12.04-on-beaglebone-%C2%BFhard-float-or-soft-float?/) by [clausqr](https://answers.ros.org/users/2426/clausqr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-05-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have hard float support in the hardware. Doing a soft float computation will just go slower.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2